# Notepad++ style configurator doesn't recognize Ruby blocked comment codes

Tags: notepad++

I'd like to modify one of the styles in Ruby to format blocked comment codes, which are written with the '=begin' and '=end' keywords. I like the Black Board theme, except comment blocks appear in black text, which is difficult to read. Notepad++ doesn't seem to recognize blocked comments for Ruby. I'd like blocked comments to display the same way at the commentLine in the style template.

```
 =begin

 This is a blocked comment.

 =end
```

Unlike other languages in the Style Configurator (e.g. php), Ruby doesn't have an option for COMMENT. In , there is a place to define comment lines.

```
 <Language name="php" ext="php php3 phtml" commentLine="//" commentStart="/*" commentEnd="*/">
 <Language name="ruby" ext="rb rbw" commentLine="#">
```

I attempted to add the commentStart and commentEnd fields to Ruby, but it didn't change anything.

I also tried adding a style for COMMENT in the style files,  and  but it still doesn't format the blocked comments.

```
 <LexerType name="ruby" desc="Ruby" ext="">
   <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" styleID="0" fgColor="F8F8F8" bgColor="0C1021" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="10" /> 
   <WordsStyle name="ERROR" styleID="1" fgColor="000000" bgColor="0C1021" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="10" /> 
   <WordsStyle name="COMMENTLINE" styleID="2" fgColor="AEAEAE" bgColor="0C1021" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="10" /> 
   *<WordsStyle name="COMMENT" styleID="2" fgColor="AEAEAE" bgColor="0C1021" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="10" />*
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

As of built-in Ruby language, I can change given color using built-in style configurator for Ruby language. The color is controlled by `POD` category. Please see the following image - hopefully it gives the idea:

[image]